# Is there a way to clear the environment.specialfolder.personal folder that goes with an iPad app?

Tags: iphone, ipad

We need to clear it, but can't have physical access to the machine. There is a built in function in the app to do that, but the app craches because of errors in that folder, so we can't get to that.

You help is much appreciated.

Comment: What about removing the app and the reinstalling it?

Comment: Yes, that would work, but I don't have physical access to the machine (and the app is not distributed throught the AppStore, but part of the dev-deployment)